# Syntax error 'continue' not properly in a loop

Tags: python, syntax

```
elif command == 'join':
    if len(params) < 1: continue
    safeexec(params[0], getattr(botimpl, 'onenter', None), (params[0], prefix))
```

it says

> Syntax error 'continue' not properly in a loop

when I run the file.

Comment: Change the `elif` to: `elif command == 'join' and len(params) >= 1: safeexec...`

Comment: You probably want to use `pass` - no `continue`.

Comment: is the `if-elif` inside a loop ? please add more code to include the if-else context

Answer (score 5):

You cannot `continue` from an `if` statement. You need it to be in a loop.

```
for x in range(10):
    if x == 4:
        continue
    # Do work
```

Whereas,

```
if x == 4:
    continue
```

is wrong.

[Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#continue) state this:

> The continue statement, also borrowed from C, continues with the next iteration of the loop:

Answer (score 0):

The `continue` keyword is used to *go directly* to the next iteration of a *loop*, skipping the code after the keyword. So, the error

```
SyntaxError: 'continue' not properly in loop
```

indicates that the  `elif` clause is not inside a loop (like `for` or `while`).

**What can you do?**

- Check your logic. Do you really want to use `continue`?
- Put the code inside a loop:

  ```
  while (...):
      if command == 'join':
          continue
  ```

Answer (score 0):

`continue` must be inside a while or for loop, check if your elif statement is within a for or while loop. if yes, check your indentation.

Answer (score 0):

[The `continue` keyword](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#continue) is reserved to skip the iteration of a loop and not a `if` condition block. What you want to do is more this:

```
elif command == 'join' and len(params) >= 1:
    safeexec(params[0], getattr(botimpl, 'onenter', None), (params[0], prefix))
```

From the documentation:

> `continue` may only occur syntactically nested in a `for` or `while` loop, but not nested in a function or class definition or `finally` clause within that loop. It continues with the next cycle of the nearest enclosing loop.
>
> When `continue` passes control out of a `try` statement with a `finally` clause, that `finally` clause is executed before really starting the next loop cycle.